# Composer not working try to get my own package after registering in Packagist

Tags: composer-php, packagist

First some background, I'm working on a local project which I uploaded to Github and register in Packagist.
the composer is install the dependecies for development

but the problem occurs when i'm trying to catch MY OWN package after registering in Packagist

I'm getting an error

This is the command I'm using:

```
➜  test  composer global require AA/AA:dev-master
```

And this is the Error:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Changed current directory to /home/a/.composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for AA/AA dev-master -> satisfiable by AA/AA
[dev-master].
        - AA/AA dev-master requires hamcrest/hamcrest-php dev-master -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

and this is my composer.json in GitHub:

```
{ 
    "name": "AA/AA",
    "description": "AA",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "hamcrest/hamcrest-php": "dev-master"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "AA",
            "email": "AA@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "AA\\": "src/" }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to either `1)` tag a version of your code on github with a symantic version number as the tag name so that packagist and composer see this as a stable version, or `2)` include a [minimum-stability setting](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) in your composer.json

Comment: Minimum stability dev has solved it. thanks